# How can I truncate the length of a string in a DataFrame Column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a `DataFrame` that contains columns with text and I want to truncate the text in a `Column` to a certain length. I tried the following operation:

```
val updatedDataFrame = dataFrame.withColumn("NewColumn", col("ExistingColumn").take(15))
```

I get the following error because I transform the `Column` instead of its content:

> notebook:7: error: value take is not a member of
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Column
>                                    .withColumn("NewColumn", col("ExistingColumn").take(15))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use method [substring](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@substring(str:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,pos:Int,len:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column), as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq( (1, "abcdef"), (2, "uvwx") ).toDF("id", "value")

df.withColumn("value3", substring($"value", 1, 3)).show
// +---+------+------+
// | id| value|value3|
// +---+------+------+
// |  1|abcdef|   abc|
// |  2|  uvwx|   uvw|
// +---+------+------+
```

Comment: What happens here if the string in `value` is shorter than 3 chars?

Comment: In that case the whole string value is preserved, without error.